# Scala Has Infinity but no Infinitesimal. Why?

Tags: scala, infinity

Open a Scala interpreter.

```
scala> 1E-200 * 1E-200    
res1: Double = 0.0

scala> 1E200 * 1E200    
res2: Double = Infinity
```

A very large product value evaluates to Infinity.
A very small value evaluates to zero.

Why not be symmetrical and create something called Infinitesimal?

Comment: All questions to [IEEE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point). Poor Scala has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this has to do with the way floating point numbers work, which has more to do with your processor than scala.  The small number is going to be so small that the closest representation corresponds to +0 (positive zero), and so it underflows to 0.0.  The large number is going to overflow past any valid representation and be replaced with +inf (positive infinity).  Remember that floating point numbers are a fixed precision estimation.  If you want a system that is more exact, you can use http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.math.BigDecimal

Comment: Infinitesimal could be used to capture the underflow event just as Infinite is used to capture the overflow event

Comment: This would not fit with floating point's role as an estimation. While there is an underflow exception described in IEEE 754, it signals loss of precision, not the presence of a special value. There are a lot of things like equality testing that floats are not made for. Getting 0.0 == 1E-200 * 1E-200 to reliably be false goes against that. (edited)

Comment: ```scala> val x =  1E200 * 1E200
    x: Double = Infinity

    scala> val y =  1E200 * 1E200
    y: Double = Infinity

    scala> x == y 
    res8: Boolean = true

    scala> val x1 =  1E-200 * 1E-200
    x1: Double = 0.0

   scala> val y1 =  1E-200 * 1E-200
   y1: Double = 0.0

   scala> x1 == y1
   res9: Boolean = true

Comment: Ignore previous comment. Cannot edit it now. Just as a point of interest:

scala> 1E200 * 1E200 == 1E199 * 1E199
res0: Boolean = true
This is obviously incorrect mathematically. 

scala> 1E-200 * 1E-200 == 1E199 * 1E199
res1: Boolean = false

scala> 1E-200 * 1E-200 == 1E-199 * 1E-199
res2: Boolean = true
This also is obviously incorrect mathematically. 

But I agree with the take away that floating point numbers are DESIGNED as an approximation mechanism and not as something that will be mathematically correct at very large or very small values.

Answer (score 0):

Scala, just like Java, follows the [IEEE specification for floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point), which does not have "infinitesimals". I'm not quite sure infinitesimals would make much sense either way, as they have no mathematical interpretation as numbers.

Comment: To my mind Infinitesimal could be the set of values too small to fit into the finite number of bits leading to limited capacity of precision. Infinitesimal does have an interpretation in calculus limits => Make something as small as it needs to be made without making it into a zero.